# Compile Error in Generated Objective-C interface

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, frameworks, openframeworks

I'm using a Swift framework in an OpenFrameworks (C++ project), which is something I've done successfully in the past. I'm able to add in the framework and import it into my Swift file.

However, I'm seeing some really odd compiler errors in my project's generated 
Objective-C interface from my Swift file, and I'm really not sure where to start troubleshooting. Anyone have any insight?

Below is a screenshot of what the errors are looking like in my generated Swift file:

[image]

Comment: That's not a Swift file, that's an Objective-C interface generated from your Swift file.

Comment: Yes, you're right; thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is wrong.  Is that the contents of the .swift file?  There shouldn't be any Objective-C in a Swift file.  What happens if you remove the class from the project and re-add it?

Comment: I hadn't event been able to add a class yet - the project builds if I remove this include statement: 

#include "exampleDebug-Swift.h"

Comment: @narner Where are you including it? It should work with either Objective-C (".m") or Objective-C++ (".mm").

Comment: @molbdnilo The problem was that I had forgotten to change the C++ files to be Obj-C source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had forgotten to change the C++ files to Objective-C++ source files. Doing that resolved the problem.